# unable to deploy servlet application in jboss

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jboss

I am new to jboss and I am developing a web servlet application with maven.
I use ear for packaging. When in deployement I am getting this error.

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: The content of element type "application" is
>   incomplete, it must match
>   "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)". @
>   *unknown*[7,15]

My application.xml file is given below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>my-app</display-name>
</application>
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What version of WildFly?

Comment: 6.1.0 is my jboss version

Comment: This application.xml file is automatically created when building the project, hence it can't be changed. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Do you mean JBoss AS 6.1.0 or JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA?

Comment: It is JBoss AS 6.1.0

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that version, but maybe it doesn't support Java EE 1.3 which is quite old. I believe JBoss AS 6 is a Java EE 5 container.